# MQTT consumer in cluster solution (akka, vert.x or ?)

Tags: apache-camel, akka, cluster-computing, mqtt, vert.x

We're starting a project, where we need to consume some messages from **MQTT** topic, but our solution needs to work in cluster with multiple nodes/instances - needs to be scalable.

The problem is, that we're not sure about what technology to choose. We're facing problem like: there needs to be only 1 consumer per cluster in other words, we need to avoid of consuming message twice (if 2 nodes)...***akka*** reportedly supports singleton in cluster so this might work, but I'm not sure how to integrate akka with MQTT.

The other possibility is ***vert.x***. Both akka and vert.x have bridges to ***camel*** or they supports protocol directly? I saw that vertx. has MQTT server integration, but I'm not quite sure if this is exactly what we need. Will it work as I imagine with wrapping camel to vert.x or akka-cluster?

Comment: https://github.com/akka/akka-stream-contrib/tree/master/mqtt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I know, you should be able to create a singleton akka camel consumer across your akka-cluster. You should do something like this:

Once you have defined your Akka Camel Consumer:

```
object CamelConsumer {
  def props = Props(new CamelConsumer())
}

class CamelConsumer extends Consumer {
    def endpointUri = "mqtt://..."

    def receive = {
      //...
    }
}
```

You can define your singleton like this:

```
context.actorOf(ClusterSingletonManager.props(
  CamelConsumer.props, 
  PoisonPill, 
  ClusterSingletonManagerSettings(context.system)), "singletonConsumer")
val singletonConsumer = context.actorOf(ClusterSingletonProxy.props(
  singletonManagerPath = "/user/app/singletonConsumer",
  settings = ClusterSingletonProxySettings(system)),
  name = "singletonConsumerProxy")
```

I have no experience with Vert.x.

Answer (score 3):

It may be worth looking at MQTT shared subscriptions (which some brokers like MessageSight or HiveMQ support): http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-load-balancing-with-shared-subscriptions/

Shared Subscriptions are a mechanism for client load balancing with MQTT, which allows to consume a message once because the subscription is shared amongst many clients. This is possible with MQTT standard mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Vert.x High Availability and Fail-Over](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_high_availability_and_fail_over) to make sure a (single) instance of your Verticle is deployed in the cluster.

Comment: Actually, I found out that camel-bridge for vert.x is used for receiving/sending messages to camel, but in fact, I need my vert.x app to be able to consume from mqtt topics directly to the event bus. I can't find support for that anywhere. Please correct me if I'm wrong.